# How to get a shapefile from a brazilian municipe, if I already get the corresponding map from GeoBr library?

Tags: python, geopandas

I've been using GeoBR and Geopandas to create maps to of samples collecting zones from a specific area of a Brazillian city. However, I need to add some other elements like wind rose, scales and other geografical requirements for publication. Thus, I want to download respective shapefiles (.shp) of these maps that I plotted to perform specific editings on ArcGis. Do you guys know some way to download these files from a geopandas plot?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geobr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

muni = geobr.read_municipality(code_muni = 'MA', year = 2020)
muni.head()

gdf_muni = muni[muni.name_muni.isin(["São Luís", "Paço Do Lumiar", "São José De Ribamar", "Raposa"])]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
base = muni.plot(ax=ax,color='white', edgecolor='black')
gdf_muni.plot(ax=base, legend=True)
ax.set_title('zonas de coleta')
plt.show()
```